In Unity, how can I check whether two objects are sliding on each other or rolling against one another?
I'm coding a script to make objects emit appropriate noises on contact with other objects, with different sounds for isolated impacts, sliding, and rolling.
Impacts work just fine, but for the other two I ran into the problem that often an object sliding across a surface will not collide with it every frame, so when I tried to tie the sliding sound to OnCollisionStay, it didn't work.
I hacked together a solution of checking whether the last time OnCollisionEnter was called was within a certain time, and if so treating the newest impact as a slide or roll (depending on the perpendicular component of collison.relativeVelocity), but I'm afraid it won't be consistent and I was wondering if there is a cleaner, more exact method to check this.

I think your time-based solution may be as good as it gets, unfortunately.

Sometimes the solution everyone recommends is not the best one: I was always told that to use a 3D object as a diegetic button, I needed to use Raycast to check whether the mouse cursor was on it, but I recently found out about the OnMouseUpWhileOver method, which accomplishes this much more efficiently. Suret doesn't check for line of sight, but that can be done in many more efficient ways

Keep in mind that using that method just means Unity is firing raycasts for you, and doing it potentially less efficiently than your own code that knows which layers/objects actually need to be involved.

Thanks for the tip.
